# NativeScript ScrollView scrollToHorizontalOffset not working

Tags: scrollview, nativescript

I have this ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView orientation="horizontal" id='scroll'>
    <StackLayout orientation='horizontal' swipe='swipe'>
      <Image src="image1" />
      <Image src="image2" />
      <Image src="image3" />
      <Image src="image4" />
     </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and js:

```
function swipe(args) {
    var scroll = args.view;
    scroll.scrollToHorizontalOffset(0, true);
}
exports.swipe = swipe;
```

I expect that every swipe I made on the scrollView, it will go to the horizontalOffset I set on scrollToHorizontalOffset but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the **scrollToHorizontalOffset** is not working is because you are trying to invoke it on the **StackLayout** when it belongs to the ScrollView. There are two things you can do:

1. `var scroll = args.view.parent` - because `view` is the StackLayout
   and you need the ScrollView, which is its parent.

### or

2. Attach the gesture directly to the ScrollView - `<ScrollView orientation="horizontal" id='scroll' swipe='swipe'>`

Comment: Thanks. I tried attaching the gesture on scrollview but still, it didnt do the scrolltohorizontaloffset..

Comment: It works when I removed the boolean on scrollToHorizontalOffset. As per the documentation, its for the animation. Hmm, how can I add animation to this? hmm

Comment: @CamilleLagrama-I edited my answer above to avoid ambiguity. I tested both of the cases. First, I included enough pictures to be able to scroll horizontally inside the view. When I scroll, let`s say, to the end of the view and I swipe - the pictures get scrolled back to the beginning. I am using {N} 1.4.3 and I am testing on iPhone simulator. Can you tell me what version and device you are using?

Comment: Yes, its working without the boolean but I want the animation on scrolling. hmm.. im using {N} 1.4.3 and testing it on an android phone and simulator with Android version 4.2.2